# Monitoring mysql server on osx

Tags: mysql, mac-osx, monitoring

Is there a good application that will run on osx (GUI) that would let me monitor the queries and other mysql server settings on a remote server?

G-Man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) (to replace MySQL Administrator GUI Tool) should do the trick. It's currently in beta, but is pretty stable from what I've seen of it on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how extensively you want to monitor it, or what kind of monitoring you want.

[Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is free, open source app that would allow you to do some monitoring.
`show processlist`, for example. Not entirely sure if this is the type of monitoring you are looking for....